# How to create log-in activity using MySql for android

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I need  an apps which will  have a log-in and sign  activity using mySql database

Comment: Your question (not even a question actually) is to broad, and don't show any effort on your part to try and make it, this make it seem like you just want us to write the code for you, and it doesn't work like that here. You should try yourself, if you encounter a problem, come here and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use webservices as jsp,servlet or any server technologies at server
>   side and hit url from android with httpok or normal httpconnection.